# System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent] in ViewComponent Section of View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to view component and don't understand why I am getting this error at all.

```
public class Last6ClosedJobsViewComponent :  ViewComponent
{
    private readonly Eva804Context ctx;

    public Last6ClosedJobsViewComponent(Eva804Context context)
    {
        ctx = context;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int id)
    {
        var jobs = from j in ctx.Job
                   .Include(j => j.Site)
                   .Include(j => j.WaterBody)
                   .Where(j => j.Site.SiteID == id && j.InvoiceDate != null)
                   .OrderByDescending(j => j.BookingDate)
                   .Take(6)
                   select j;

        return View(jobs);
    }

}
```

Then in the default view I am simply trying to show a  list of booking dates, at this stage:

```
@model IEnumerable<Eva804.Models.Job>

<h3>Recently Invoiced Jobs</h3>
<ul>
@foreach (var j in Model)
{
    <li>@j.BookingDate</li>

}
</ul>
```

Then in site details I have the following:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">@Component.InvokeAsync("Last6ClosedJobs",Model.SiteID)</div>
```

All of which looks correct as far as I can see, compared to the examples I am working against.

This is then showing in the view a loverly green section, nice and wording as:
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent]

How do I find this error?  Where should I look?  Is there something wrong with my code I cant see?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need `@await` to handle ansynchronous calls, like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">@await Component.InvokeAsync("Last6ClosedJobs",Model.SiteID)</div>
```

`InvokeAsync` returns a Task, then `@await` waits on the task and when the task is finished, it returns the result.